# Is it possible to run another script while current script is running?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am making a standalone text-based game much like the old time MUD games. My question: Is it possible to run an alternate script while main one is running.
In traditional MUD games this is handled by the server, but I am trying to emulate say for instance:

```
import time
While FIGHT_MODE:
    # Do fight stuff
    # time.sleep(5) # Waits 5 seconds before looping
```

But in the mean time say I want to type in

```
kick
```

this should call another script while in the loop to do what it is supposed to do. Can anyone give some suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Use [`os.fork`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork).

Comment: The [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package is probably your best bet, it provides a high-level interface for working with multiple asynchronous control paths.